# NoClassDefFoundError android flex ane extension

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I created a ane native extension for a flex application and I have a problem. 
My problem is that i get a NoClassDefFoundError from native java code. The class that is not found is in a third-party jar. I added the third-party jar as a lib file in eclipse, is also set on project build pats and is also set as exported resource. 
I think the problem is when i pack the final .jar file for the extension. I unpacked the .jar file and the third-party jar is there.

Comment: what if you put your third-party jar near your result jar, not inside it?

Comment: bassed on adobe documentation and other native extensions that I already used this method has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful when packaging a third party library with your Java ANE. You often need to unpack the third party jar file and include the class files along with your own.

```
jar xf 3rd_party_lib.jar
```

Then repackage your ANE library jar

```
jar uf your_native_ane_libary.jar [directory of all your class files]
```

You have to do this just before using adt to package your ANE.