# Adobe air native extension with android external jars (aapt tool failed:ERROR)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, air-native-extension

I have a native android extension that referencing an android library project.
Inside referenced android library project I have several "JARs" in the "lib" folder.

[image]

I use eclipse to export a final "JAR" that referenced by the "extesion.xml" file.
All other jars that used to be included in the "libs" folder are referenced by dependancies xml file. that looks like this :

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/14.0">
<packagedDependencies>
    <packagedDependency>async-http-client-1.8.6.jar</packagedDependency>
    <packagedDependency>netty-3.9.0.Final.jar</packagedDependency>
    <packagedDependency>slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar</packagedDependency>
    <packagedDependency>slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar</packagedDependency>
    <packagedDependency>wasync-1.3.2.jar</packagedDependency>
</packagedDependencies>
<packagedResources>
</packagedResources>
```

Here how I export the final JAR using eclipse :
[image]

Now here is the command line that I use to build my ANE file :

```
adt -package -target ane GDAndroidNativeExtention.ane extension.xml -swc GDAndroidNativeExtention.swc -platform Android-ARM -platformoptions platform-options-android.xml -C android . -platform default -C default .
```

That builds me a nice ANE file which I then copy pasting into my IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 .
However when I am trying to compile to android the following error appears :
[image]

> aapt tool failed:ERROR: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe Gaming SDK 1.3\AIR SDK\lib\android\lib\resources\android-res.jar' is not a directory

Well I would really like to know what it means and how it can be fixed.

I do know that the same extension works when I am compiling it without "platformoptions" command .But when I do that application runs but does not executes the code that referenced in jars. I can clearly see in the logcat messages like :

> Could not find class 'com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder', referenced from method com.gd.server.connector.internal.http.TRXAtmosphereConnection.createConfigurableSocket

And I did already try to include those jars while exporting my extension from eclipse.It didn't see references to those jars even in that case.

Bottom line all I need is my extension to work.And I will be happy to know of any alternatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the right thing to do in this situation is to flag your own question as a duplicate; at least, if the provided answer to the other question worked without modification. Otherwise, post what modifications you made in your own answer below. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError android flex ane extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041085/noclassdeffounderror-android-flex-ane-extension)

Comment: I marked as a possible duplicate.Though I choose to workaround the problem using another solution , there is still no solution to the error posted in the question . I think my question is descriptive , and can help someone to find a correct solution .